# Is there a way to make a UICollectionView with cells in a criss cross pattern?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am setting up a collection view for my app in which there are going to be cells in a cross pattern like given in the image below:

[image]

I couldn't find a way to do this, and as I am new to this I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Think the circles have wrappers like this https://i.imgur.com/nqE8uA5.png , you will see that is actually like pinterest style collectionview, it seems to possible with creating a UICustomCollectionViewLayout https://medium.com/@andersongusmao/uicollectionview-using-cells-with-different-heights-6627f053cdcd

Comment: @ocanal Thank you so much I will follow the tutorial in the link. Much appreciated!